# How to schedule a java code having messageArrived method of MqttCallback

Tags: java, server, mqtt

I am new in MQTT world. I have written a code to subscribe a topic and get message from topic and store it in database. Now my problem is how to put this code on server so that it will keep receiving message infinitely. I am trying to create a scheduler but in that case i am Getting Persistence Already in Use error from MQTT. I cannot change the clientId every time it connect. It is a fixed one in my case. Is there any way to get the persistence object which is already connected for a particular clientId?

Please help. Thanks and advance.

Please Find the code subscribe topic and messageArrived method of mqqt to get message from topic

```
public class AppTest {
private MqttHandler handler;

public void doApp() {
    // Read properties from the conf file
    Properties props = MqttUtil.readProperties("MyData/app.conf");

    String org = props.getProperty("org");
    String id = props.getProperty("appid");
    String authmethod = props.getProperty("key");
    String authtoken = props.getProperty("token");
    // isSSL property
    String sslStr = props.getProperty("isSSL");
    boolean isSSL = false;
    if (sslStr.equals("T")) {
        isSSL = true;
    }

    // Format: a:<orgid>:<app-id>
    String clientId = "a:" + org + ":" + id;
    String serverHost = org + MqttUtil.SERVER_SUFFIX;

    handler = new AppMqttHandler();
    handler.connect(serverHost, clientId, authmethod, authtoken, isSSL);

    // Subscribe Device Events
    // iot-2/type/<type-id>/id/<device-id>/evt/<event-id>/fmt/<format-id>
    handler.subscribe("iot-2/type/" + MqttUtil.DEFAULT_DEVICE_TYPE
            + "/id/+/evt/" + MqttUtil.DEFAULT_EVENT_ID + "/fmt/json", 0);
}

/**
 * This class implements as the application MqttHandler
 *
 */
private class AppMqttHandler extends MqttHandler {

    // Pattern to check whether the events comes from a device for an event
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("iot-2/type/"
            + MqttUtil.DEFAULT_DEVICE_TYPE + "/id/(.+)/evt/"
            + MqttUtil.DEFAULT_EVENT_ID + "/fmt/json");
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper();

    /**
     * Once a subscribed message is received
     */
    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage)
            throws Exception {
        super.messageArrived(topic, mqttMessage);

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(topic);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String payload = new String(mqttMessage.getPayload());

            // Parse the payload in Json Format
            JSONObject contObj = new JSONObject(payload);
            System.out
                    .println("jsonObject arrived in AppTest : " + contObj);
            // Call method to insert data in database
            dbHelper.insertIntoDB(contObj);
        }
    }
}
```

Code to connect to client

```
public void connect(String serverHost, String clientId, String authmethod,
        String authtoken, boolean isSSL) {
    // check if client is already connected
    if (!isMqttConnected()) {
        String connectionUri = null;

        //tcp://<org-id>.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:1883
        //ssl://<org-id>.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:8883
        if (isSSL) {
            connectionUri = "ssl://" + serverHost + ":" + DEFAULT_SSL_PORT;
        } else {
            connectionUri = "tcp://" + serverHost + ":" + DEFAULT_TCP_PORT;
        }

        if (client != null) {
            try {
                client.disconnect();
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            client = null;
        }

        try {
            client = new MqttClient(connectionUri, clientId);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        client.setCallback(this);

        // create MqttConnectOptions and set the clean session flag
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setCleanSession(false);

        options.setUserName(authmethod);
        options.setPassword(authtoken.toCharArray());

        //If SSL is used, do not forget to use TLSv1.2
        if (isSSL) {
            java.util.Properties sslClientProps = new java.util.Properties();
            sslClientProps.setProperty("com.ibm.ssl.protocol", "TLSv1.2");
            options.setSSLProperties(sslClientProps);
        }

        try {
            // connect
            client.connect(options);
            System.out.println("Connected to " + connectionUri);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You just need to start the mqtt client, and subscribe, it will then run until it's stopped and the `messageArrived` method will be called every time a new message is delivered, there is not need to keep reconnecting. The error is because you are trying to start multiple clients at the same time

Comment: @hardillb Thank you for your comment. Yes exactly the same thing i want to do but i dont know how to put it on server and start it. I have tried scheduling it but failed. Also how it will restart once it stopped. Please help with some example. I am using bluemix server right now.